# Is it possible to have Castor marshal/unmarshal an EnumMap?

Tags: java, castor

I'm using Castor to marshal/unmarshal my Java objects, one of which contains an EnumMap. 
Can Castor marshal/unmarshal EnumMaps? I have a mapping file with some nested HashMaps, but I've never pushed an EnumMap through Castor. If it is possible, how is it done through the mapping file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big problems is that Enums can't really be serialized and restored, at least not in Java 1.5. And I think also not in Java 1.6.

As enums can not - by default - be serialized or XMLEncoded I very much doubt an EnumMap can be serialized. From the [castor web page](https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guide/reference/xml/xml-mapping.html) :

> While you can always use your own
>   custom FieldHandler for handling
>   type-safe enumeration classes, Castor
>   does have a built-in approach to
>   dealing with these types of classes.
>   If the type-safe enum class has a
>   public static  valueOf(String)
>   method Castor will call that method so
>   that the proper instance of the
>   enumeration is returned. Note: You'll
>   also need to disable the default
>   constructor check in the mapping file
>   (see section 7.4 above to see more on
>   this).

if that does not work you have to write your own [field handler](https://castor-data-binding.github.io/castor/reference-guide/reference/xml/xml-fieldhandlers.html).

I hope this helps a bit.